# Jmeter: Unable to pass extracted value using Regular expression to a new http request

Tags: regex, jmeter

Regular expression works on the response correctly in Results tree

When I pass extracted value using the Variable in Jmeter to a subsequent request, the new request is not getting the value from the Regex variable. Please let me know what is missing here?

### **Sample of previous response data is below**

{"TimeSheetIID":138701753.0,"CrewAssignedHourID":"ID138701753","Description":" ","StartDate":null,"TimeSheetType":3,"EnterTimeBy":0,"Status":"New","IncludeAllBookings":0.0,"Orders":[],"SelectedOrders":[],"Resources":[],"SelectedResources":[],"Positions":[],"SelectedPositions":[],"ViewModelState":null,"ScreenId":null,"ScreenSecurityDefinitions":null,"DirtyFields":null,"UserDefinedFields":null,"IsDeleted":false,"IsSelected":false,"IID":138701753.0}

**Tested Regular Expression on the above response and working**
(?<="TimeSheetIID":)(.)*(?=.0,"Crew)
Have created Reg expression extractor with variable name tid

**New request not fetching data from Regular Expression**

POST data:
{"fieldiid":"0","parentjson":"{\"TimeSheetIID\":***${tid}***,\"CrewAssignedHourID\":\"\",\"Description\":\" \",\"StartDate\":null,\"TimeSheetType\":3,\"EnterTimeBy\":0,\"Status\":\"New\",\"IncludeAllBookings\":0,\"Orders\":[],\"SelectedOrders\":[],\"Resources\":[],\"SelectedResources\":[],\"Positions\":[],\"SelectedPositions\":[],\"ViewModelState\":null,\"ScreenId\":null,\"ScreenSecurityDefinitions\":null,\"DirtyFields\":null,\"UserDefinedFields\":null,\"IsDeleted\":false,\"IsSelected\":false,\"IID\":***${tid}***}"}

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to use JSONPATH instead of RegExp while extracting key-value pair from response JSON. I tried your regexp above in JMeter 4.0 and it did not work. 
Observed `org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression:`

I could successfully extract value for TimeSheetIID using this RegExp -

```
"TimeSheetIID":(.+?)\.
```

Update : Here is a snapshot of actually working JMeter script.
[PFA Working script snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qml0Y.jpg)

[regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter)

Comment: Issue here is, when the output of Regular expression is passed to the new http request, the new http request is not getting the value. The POST data still gets it as ${tid} instead of the value 138701753

Comment: I had verified that next http request indeed gets the extracted value of regexp. I have updated my response with screenshot of working script.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the regex here https://regex101.com

```
TimeSheetIID":(\d+.?\d*),"CrewAssignedHourID":"(\w+)",
```

the (\d+.?\d*) will get you the timesheet decimal number. the (\w+) will get you the crew AssignedHourId.

[image]

> ```
> \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
> + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> .? matches any character (except for line terminators)
> ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> \d* matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
> * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to handle JSON response, with JSON Path Expressions

```
 $.TimeSheetIID
```

Choose Match No. 1 and choose name `tid`  as variable name for next request